# Filter all records based on a flag in the relational table

Tags: mysql, sql

OK so I have two tables

products:

```
+------------+----------------+
| product_id | name           |
+------------+----------------+
|          1 | A product here |
+------------+----------------+
|          2 | B product here |
+------------+----------------+
```

and sellers

```
+------------+----------------+------------+
| seller_id  | in_stock       | product_id |
+------------+----------------+------------+
|          1 | 1              | 1          |
+------------+----------------+------------+
|          2 | 0              | 1          |
+------------+----------------+------------+
|          2 | 0              | 2          |
+------------+----------------+------------+
```

I'm trying to figure out how to return only products where all sellers have `in_stock = 0`.

So in this particular example it would only return the product with product_id of 2 because product_id has one row with in_stock=1

Comment: Please add the expected output table also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the maximum of the in_stock column for this product has to be 0:

```
SELECT 
    product_id
FROM
    sellers
GROUP BY
    product_id
HAVING
    MAX(in_stock) = 0;
```

So you get the product info with a join

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    products
INNER JOIN (
   SELECT 
        product_id
    FROM
        sellers
    GROUP BY
        product_id
    HAVING
        MAX(in_stock) = 0
) t
ON
    products.product_id = t.product_id;
```

Comment: See the fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a6052/5 to prove that the above answer works.

Comment: @Rahul, thanks I wanted to provide one myself, but you were faster.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the below to account for products not sold by any sellers (essentially equating to not being in stock), as well as those products that are sold by sellers but which are all out of stock.

```
select product_id
  from sellers
 group by product_id
having max(in_stock) = 0
union all
select p.product_id
  from products p
  left join sellers s
    on p.product_id = s.product_id
 where s.product_id is null
```